# No response or errorResponse from JSONArrayRequest

Tags: java, android-volley

I have a script in Android studio what when start a new activity that makes a request for XML data from a pageweb,
I do a JSONArrayRequest which worked until recently, i don't remember what i touched and i'm still learning...
When start getInfo call start the request, i have a callback interface for waiting the end of request.
But when instantiate a new JsonArrayRequest he ignore OnResponse and ErrorResponse and jump until mRequestQueue.add(request).
The url is correct, I tried to open it by copying it from the value in debug

I have a method that send a notification when the activity start:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    try{
        getInfo(new VolleyCallBack(){
            public void OnSuccess(){
                sendLocalNotification(myClass.getName(), "pluto");
            }});
    }
    catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

The method that send the notification:

```
private void sendLocalNotification(String titolo, String text)
{
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "channelX")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle(titolo)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    int id = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    notificationManager.notify(id , notification);
}
```

And a method that extracts the data from the page and saves it in a Beam class.

But now ignore both the OnResponse and ErrorResponse.

```
private void getInfo(final VolleyCallBack CallBack) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException
{
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    String url = getUrl();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, jsonArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response){
            JSONObject object;
            myClass = new MyClass();
            for (int index = 0; index < response.length(); index++)
                try{
                    object = response.getJSONObject(index);
                    if (!object.getBoolean("exist")
                            && object.getInt("_id") != 0){
                        myClass.set_id(object.getString("_id"));
                        myClass.set_name(object.getStrig("name"));
                        myClass.set_exist(object.getStrig("exist"));
                        callBack.OnSuccess();
                        break;}

                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError err){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);}
```

A reproduction of xml data:

```xml
<ArrayOfXXX xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/XXXXX">
<NameObject>
<name/>
<_id>012345</_id>
<exist>false</exist>
</NameObject>
<NameObject>
<name/>
<_id>0</_id>
<exist>false</exist>
</NameObject>
</ArrayOfXXX>
```

I don't know what happened...

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (formatted consistently) and an according language tag. Further, do a simple web search of the error that you get so that you have a basic understanding what it means. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: You mention you didn't change anything. Then, the problem is not in the code but on the remote side and no question here concerning your code can change that.

Comment: I did it. The case is really simple. That's why I don't understand why it doesn't work!

Comment: You did what? It's still not formatted consistent, it's still not a [mcve] and there's still no language tagged to your question.

Comment: Your question is actually confusing .... make it more clear

Comment: i hope it's correct now.

Comment: I've just added the android-volley tag (pending approval) as I think this question is too specialized for anyone who doesn't know anything about Volley. The tag should help bring the question to people with the right kind of knowledge.

Comment: Thanks!! I had added the android studio tag but maybe it was too generic...